# I'd like to know the implication of "small" and "big"

Tags: word-usage

Instead of "She's short." can I say, "She's small."?
Instead of "She's tall." can I say, "She's big."?
I'd like to know the implication of "small" and "big" when describing people's appearance.
Also another question is that instead of "When I was a child," can I say, "When I was small"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general, *tall* and *short* refer to a person's height, while *big* and *small* refer to a person's bulk.

*Big* can apply to a person's height, but it's just as likely to refer to a person's weight.

As an example, Shaquille O'Neal‎ is big. Dikembe Mutombo is tall.

[image: big and tall]

This isn't to say that Shaquille is not tall, or that Dikembe is not big. However, if you were describing someone I didn't know, and you said, "She's big," I'd assume you were talking about her dress size more than her height. Similarly, words like *small* or *tiny* can refer to height or body type, so they are much more vague than *short*, which alludes to height only.

Comment: Yes. And yes, OP may say "When I was small" for "When I was a child".

Comment: @StoneyB: Yes, thanks for answering that last part of the question. "When I was little" can mean "when I was young," but we _wouldn't_ say "when I was short" to mean "when I was young."

Comment: I certainly wouldn't, because I am *still* short :)

Comment: As the Bee Gees used to sing back when I myself was (relatively) little... [When I was small, and christmas trees were tall,...](http://www.lyricsfreak.com/b/bee+gees/first+of+may_20015633.html)